# Hide rows on another sheet based on a group of cells then print

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets "Main" and "CheckList".

The "Main" worksheet has selections in cells B14:B29 and in cells E14:E21 (by selections I mean I have made is so that when these cells are activated they auto fill with an X). I also have a button on the page labeled "Print"

The "CheckList" page is a check list.

I want to when I press the button labeled "Print" to 
 - filter out/hide rows on the "CheckList" based on what boxes are selected on the "Main" worksheet
 - print the "CheckList" to the default printer.

For example if Main B14 has an X (can I also make it where it isn't case sensitive?) then rows 6-10 will be hidden, if B15 has an X then rows 106-116 will be hidden. It'll be a different set of rows for every X in the ranges I mentioned.

I was also curious if this can be accomplished using groups so that it will be easier for someone to come behind me and add items to the check list with out changing the code.

Comment: Is your question answered with the additional information about naming of a range? If yes, please consider to "accept the answer" as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here is your example, either hiding the rows or grouping them and showing rowlevel 1.

If you give a name (by Formulas | Name Manager) to each relevant area on your checklist, then you may exchange `Range("6:10")` by `Range("RowsToBeHiddenByB14")`. If someone else later adds some rows within a named range on the checklist, the code still works - otherwise he has to adapt the range of that name within Excel's Name Manager.

```
Private Sub HideOrGroupSomeRows()
    Dim MainSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CheckSheet As Worksheet

    Set MainSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    Set CheckSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CheckList")

    ' Either just hide the rows:
    CheckSheet.Range("6:10").EntireRow.Hidden = _
        StrComp(MainSheet.Range("B14").Value, "x", vbTextCompare) = 0
    CheckSheet.Range("106:116").EntireRow.Hidden = _
        StrComp(MainSheet.Range("B15").Value, "x", vbTextCompare) = 0

    ' Or group them and show rowlevel 1:
    CheckSheet.UsedRange.ClearOutline
    With CheckSheet.Outline
        .AutomaticStyles = False
        .SummaryRow = xlAbove
        .SummaryColumn = xlLeft
    End With
    If StrComp(MainSheet.Range("B14").Value, "x", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then _
        CheckSheet.Range("6:10").EntireRow.Group
    If StrComp(MainSheet.Range("B15").Value, "x", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then _
        CheckSheet.Range("106:116").EntireRow.Group
    CheckSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1

    Set MainSheet = Nothing
    Set CheckSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome thank you i will start playing with that. Is there away to get it to just reference the group so that if some one comes in behind me and adds a item/row to the check list inside of the group the code wont have to be modified?

Comment: If you give the range a name, then you may exchange `Range("6:10")` by `Range("GivenName")`